# Set a Table in Oracle to Only Accept Certain Values for a Column

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design

I am looking to create a table that will only accept certain values in my database and I came across the default values option but I am sure that this won't be something that would work but just wanted to clarify.

As far as I am aware the default option, would allow you to store a value for a row unless this is overwritten by something else.

What I am looking to do is create a table where the STATUS column would only have the values OPEN or CLOSED so my output looks like the following:

```
ORDER_ID: 001, 002, 003
STATUS: OPEN, CLOSED, OPEN
ORDER_DATE: 2021-05-29 09:01:25, 2021-05-31 17:35:40, 2021-06-01 15:33:55
```

The table I have created so far looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS (
    ORDER_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    STATUS VARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL,
    ORDER_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ORDER_ID)
);
```

I am guessing I need to change the create table query for the order_id to include AUTO_INCREMENT but it's more the status that I want to understand in terms of how to only accept certain values.

Comment: You are looking for [a CHECK constraint](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE) - look at the [examples](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE), particularly for `office`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a constraint. Either a `check` constraint with hardcoded values that the column is allowed. Or you can create a foreign key to a table which contains the allowed values.

Comment: Thanks Andrew and Alex, thats exactly what I was looking for.